# Invalid Input '^' while doing portforward in cisco router

Tags: cisco, openvpn, nat, port-forwarding

I am using Open VPN and able to access it internally. Now to access it from outside, I am trying to do a port forward on Cisco Configuration Professional Express.

I am logging into cisco console using Putty.

After refering to few posts , I came up with this command:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 10.0.0.143 443 <EXTERNAL_IP> 443
```

But as soon as I execute this command, I am getting this error,

> % Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

Error screen,

[image]

Comment: https://image.slidesharecdn.com/day1-130716090449-phpapp01/95/day-1-introduction-to-ios-and-cisco-routers-22-638.jpg - at which part is it pointing?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler, below nat, updated the screen shot

Comment: What model of Cisco router is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, Cisco Configuration Professional Express 2.7